# What is the default behavior of rails mass assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Under rails 3.1 If I create a fresh new rails project, and scaffold a new resource like this:

```
rails g scaffold User name:string email:string
```

The create action will be like this by default:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

what I am wondering is, since there is no `attr_accessible` defined in User model, why this create would work if I post the form to this action. Since attr_accessible will allow mass-assign, but what's the default here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default in Rails is that mass assignment of any database attributes is allowed, you will not need to define that name and email string within the context of attr_accessible for them to able to be mass-assigned.

Now, attr_accessible is useful if you wish to define a whitelist of attributes that could be massed assigned, if attr_accessible is defined, then **only** the attributes within attr_accessible will be mass-assigned.

Similarly, attr_protected is used to define blacklist of attributes that cannot be used in mass assignment.

None of these things take place **unless you define these properties** however, that's why your code works fine without attr_accessible. I personally perfer whitelist approach over the blacklist approach simply because it's much more secure. Although your application works without attr_accessible, in the end, it is advised you use them anyways as a security precaution.

Comment: Couldn't have said it any better. Excellent description @Ken Li